# Cocoa POST issue

Tags: cocoa, post, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I´m newbie with Cocoa. I have one issue when I want to send data to my WS via POST

I have RequestPost program to inherit on all my projects

```
//
//  RequestPost.h
//
//  Created by Roberto on 10/01/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 CEM. All rights reserved.
//
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol DelegadoRedPost <NSObject>

-(void) terminaDescarga:(NSData*)datos conID:(NSInteger) id;
-(void) errorDescarga:(NSInteger)codigo conID:(NSInteger) id;

@end

@interface RequestPost : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject <DelegadoRedPost> *delegado;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *buffer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLConnection  *conexion;

-(void)descargar:(NSString*)direccion datosPost:(NSString*)datos conId:(NSInteger)id;


@end

//
//  RequestPost.m
//
//  Created by Roberto on 10/01/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 CEM. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RequestPost.h"

@implementation RequestPost

-(void)descargar:(NSString*)direccion datosPost:(NSString*)datos conId:(NSInteger)id
{
    self.id = id;

    NSURL *url            = [NSURL URLWithString:direccion];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //NSString *strLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", datos.length]; aqui comento 18 abr 2016
    NSString *strLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)datos.length];

    [req addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [req addValue:strLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody:[datos dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    self.conexion = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if(self.conexion){
        self.buffer = [NSMutableData data];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Métodos del Delegado de NSURLConnection

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.buffer.length = 0;
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [self.buffer appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [self.delegado terminaDescarga:self.buffer conID:self.id];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    [self.delegado errorDescarga:error.code conID:self.id];
}

@end
```

Now, when I want to inherit last files I have gotten an error .... Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSObject     ... In the line **request.delegado = self**;

This is the code when inherit

```
-(void) request
{
    RequestPost *request = [[RequestPost alloc] init];
    request.delegado = self;
    NSString *postStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"datos=%@",self.json];
    NSString *strUrl = @"http://www.futho7.com/WebService/subir_datos.php";
    [request descargar:strUrl datosPost:postStr conId:100];
}
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: `RequestPost` as it is described here doesn't implement the required protocol for the delegate, `DelegadoRedPost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .m file that contains the `request` method, you need to indicate that the class conforms to the `DelegadoRedPost` protocol and implement the required protocol methods.

Add this just before the `@implementation` line:

```
@interface WhateverClassNameThisIs () <DelegadoRedPost>

@end
```

Obviously replace `WhateverClassNameThisIs` with the actual name of this class.

As a side note, you should change the declaration of the `delegado` property from:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject <DelegadoRedPost> *delegado;
```

to:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<DelegadoRedPost> *delegado;
```

Note the two changes - delegates should normally be `weak`, not `strong`. This avoids reference cycles. And the type should be with `id`, not `NSObject`. The protocol itself extends the `NSObject` protocol.

Comment: thanks rmaddy I don´t find where I have to change the declaration of the delegado property

Comment: You only have one line that declares the `delegado`. It's posted in your question. Just change that one line like I show in the 2nd half of my answer. But to be clear, that has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: I did the change, now I have gotten an error in that line ... Propertywith weak attribute must be of object type

Comment: Forget that change for now. Your real issue is solved with the 1st half of my answer.

Comment: OKS on the RequestPost.m on the connectionDidFinishLoading method the program stoped in the next line [self.delegado terminaDescarga:self.buffer conID:self.id];  Obviously on the @implementation class I have this method (terminaDescarga)